# displaying balance in core data

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nstableview, key-value-coding

I have 3 entities in an example app:

**Account**

- name
- balance (NSDecimalNumber overall balance of account)
- balances (to-many relationship with Balances)
- transactions (many-to-many relationship with Transaction.accounts)

**Transaction**

- payee
- amount
- accounts (many-to-many relationship with Account.transactions)
- balances (many-to-one relationship with Balances.transaction)

**Balance**

- amount
- account (one-to-many relationship with Account.balances)
- transaction (one-to-many relationship with Transaction.balances)

I want to display the transactions of a particular account in an NSTableView.  The problem comes in when I want to display the balance of the current account.  Because a transaction may be associated with multiple accounts, it may have multiple balances.  I can't think of a way to select the particular balance associated with the current account being displayed in an NSTableColumn.  Does anyone have any suggestions of how to change the model or how to connect things up to the NSTableView in such a way that the proper balance is displayed?

The only thing I can think of is to create a sub-class of NSCell that knows how to select the balance associated with the current account view or an NSValueTransformer that does a similar thing.  This seems like a very inelegant solution though.  If there is a better way I would like to know how.

**Update**

Here's a screenshot of a demo app that illustrates the above.  I would like the far right column to display the balance as of that specific transaction.  Works well enough if the transaction has a balance attribute; however, in my app the balance is stored in a separate table because there may be multiple types of balances for each transaction.  I can't figure out how to get it to display the proper balance in the table view though:

[image: screenshot of potential app]

Comment: So the Balance column is to show the balance of the selected account as reduced/increased by the transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered populating the table via this NSTableViewDataSource method:

```
- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView setObjectValue:(id)anObject forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
```

I know, it looks ugly, but you can do somersaults with it.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of that.  It's sort of ugly because I don't get all the nice features of NSArrayController, but it works ;)

Answer (score 0):

Bind the table column's `value` binding to your array controller of Accounts with the controller key `selection` and the model key path `balance`.

Comment: that would only show the balance for the overall account, I want to show the balance at each transaction.

Comment: @Cayden: Huh? Perhaps you should edit your question to include a screenshot of your UI.

Comment: added a screenshot.  Hopefully what I'm looking to do is a bit clearer, it's just like a check register.  Unfortunately each transaction can participate in multiple accounts so there are multiple balances... just can't figure out how to display the one for the account that is getting viewed.